# Heroku clojure repl gives java.lang.RuntimeException: No such var: repl/profile

Tags: heroku, clojure

I've been running this app for a while, and the web part seems to work fine.  The repl did as well.  But this morning 'heroku run lein repl' returns

> java.lang.RuntimeException: No such var: repl/profile

I have been requiring minimum Leiningen 2.0.0, but if I remove that requirement in `project.clj`, the repl will load with version 1.7.0 or so.

I've noticed a few changes recently to `leiningen/standalone_repl.clj` in GitHub, but none that seem to explain the breakage.

Running the repl in the project locally works fine.  Creating a clean, empty project and requiring leiningen 2.0.0 causes the same breakage.

Comment: could you include at least the part of your project.clj where you require leiningen? It would help me understand the question much more easily

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that I'm misunderstanding the question, and if so please forgive, though just to clear up a potential misconception: You almost never need to include leiningen in a project's dependencies unless you are developing a lein plugin.

Comment: The tutorial I started on strongly encouraged Leiningen 2, so I did so, and added that requirement in my project:

:description "FIXME: write this!"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.2.3"]
                 [postgresql/postgresql "8.4-702.jdbc4"]
                 [clj-time "0.4.4"]
                 [clj-http "0.6.3"]
                 [cheshire "5.0.1"]
                 [noir "1.3.0-beta3"]]
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"

Is this not the correct approach?

Comment: That is correct. As suspected I was misinterpreting the question. I was thinking that you had added leiningen to the :dependencies section.

Answer (score 0):

It's a heroku problem. Leningen creator (and Heroku employee) [left a comment about it](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/clojure/UqRSGWWBtkA/discussion) on the clojure google group:

> This is due to the release of Leiningen 2.0.0; the buildpack currently
>   back-ports a bugfix to the repl via an alias in a way that only works
>   in the preview. For the time being you can use `lein trampoline repl`
>   explicitly; I'll push a fix for the alias tomorrow. Thanks for
>   bringing this to my attention.